# Datagridview using excel file as datasource in c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, datasource

I am trying read an excel file and once read, want to have it as a datasource for a gridview.

I have following code, the datatable gets populated fine, 
But some reason, it doesn't refresh the gridview. Not sure why, can someone help please?

```
string connPath = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";ExtendedProperties = \"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;\";"; 
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connPath); 
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM ["+aSheet+"$]", conn);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

adapter.Fill(dt); 
aGridView.DataSource = dt; 
aGridView.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

how about putting something like this

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataSet ds = new Dataset();
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();

adapter.Fill(dt);
ds = dt.Tables[0].DefaultView
bs.DataSource = ds;
aGridView.DataSource = bs.DataSource;
```